# Identifying Saddle-node bifurcation of a 3D system of ODEs

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, stability, bifurcation

I am trying to understand and prove the results shown in the following article. However, I am stuck at a point where it is stated that saddle-node bifurcation of periodic orbits occurs at approximately $\alpha =7.301$. I am struggling to figure it out from the phase portrait. How is it a saddle-node bifurcation? Apart from looking at the phase portrait, is there any other method to demonstrate it? My phase portrait with two different initial points are added where the black dots are equilibria[image].[image]

*Khibnik, Alexander I.; Roose, Dirk; Chua, Leon O.*, [**On periodic orbits and homoclinic bifurcations in Chua’s circuit with a smooth nonlinearity**](https://doi.org/10.1142/S021812749300026X), Int. J. Bifurcation Chaos Appl. Sci. Eng. 3, No. 2, 363-384 (1993). [ZBL0870.58078](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0870.58078).